# How to remove white space in between two word in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm working with MS word and I noticed that when I double space and use footnotes, the program adds a necessary page break in the middle of a sentence. How can I fix this so the writing fills the page, even if a footnote is present?

Here is a picture of my screen with the necessary page break in the middle of a sentence. [image: screenshot]

Thank You!

Comment: Well the way it looks, if the last two lines of the paragraph are on the top page, there there is not enough space for the second footnote. What happens if you reduce the linespace for footnotes only?

Comment: See Improving the Bottom Line by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BottomLine.htm#Footnotes Footnotes must be on the same page as the referencing text in Word.